# Error in sending email

Tags: php

I'm sending the email using the php script.I wanna to display the user name in from and his email id in reply path.I'm using the following code.I'm using the html in message.

```
 Error.: It is not showing the from in email , showing unknow sender.


  <?php  
 $name="TEST TEST";
 $from1=test@gmail.com
 $msg='<div>hello dfjdk faofd akfda </div>';
 $to =$email;
 $subject = $ab." Return SMS";
  $message = $msg;
  $from1 = 'test@yahoo.com';
  $headers = "From:$name\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $from1\r\n";
   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
  ?>
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you were to actually post the error you are getting

Comment: `$from1='test@gmail.com';`

Comment: It is not showing the from in email , showing unknow sender.

Comment: If your post perfectly copies the code then @Fabian Tamp is right and you are missing double quotes and a semicolon in the line of $from1. Change it to $from1="test@gmail.com";  In your code the 'from' is only included through the headers and should come up as 'From: TEST TEST" otherwise I have difficulty understanding your problem

Comment: but it is not showing TEST TEST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this one a try:

```
<?php  
  $to = $email;
  $subject = $ab." Return SMS";
  $message = '<div>hello dfjdk faofd akfda </div>';
  $name = "TEST TEST";
  $from1 = "test@gmail.com";
  $headers = "From: $name <$from1>\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $name <$from1>\r\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your markup is all wrong.

```
$from=test@gmail.com
```

This is not valid php. $from = "test@gmail.com" is however.

Next, in your first header line, the `From:$name` is also a problem. The `$name` should be the e-mail of the sender.